# JavaScript displaying just 2 decimal places without the entire value

Tags: javascript

I'm not the person who did the code,
The problem is:
I need a financial showing format like "$15.000,00" but this code just gave me 15.00
I think it is a simple thing but I just couldn't find it yet

```html
<script>
function mascaraValor(valor) {
    valor = valor.toString().replace(/\D/g,"");
    valor = valor.toString().replace(/(\d)(\d{8})$/,"$1.$2");
    valor = valor.toString().replace(/(\d)(\d{5})$/,"$1.$2");
    valor = valor.toString().replace(/(\d)(\d{2})$/,"$1,$2");
    return valor                    
}

var i;
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("customfields");
var cunitario;
var vanual;

cunitario = document.getElementsByClassName("valor1");
element = document.getElementsByClassName("valoranual1");
vanual =  parseFloat(cunitario[0].innerHTML.replace(",", ".")) * 12;
element[0].innerHTML = mascaraValor(vanual.toFixed(2));


</script>
```

Comment: Please edit the HTML/CSS/JS snippet.  First, html should go into the HTML box, not Javascript box.  Second, your javascript throws an error.  Use the snippet tool to get the included example working.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)?

Comment: Not even knew that there was a documentation for this, I'm a real beginner.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: @DanielFarrell so sorry but I simply don't know how to use stackoverflow in the correctly way

Comment: I got you started by editing your post to put the `<script>` tags in the *HTML* section of the snippet.  Now you can take it from here, editing the javascript until it reproduces your   behavior.  You can add more HTML above the `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

My co-worker fixed just putting another .replace

```js
vanual =  parseFloat(cunitario[0].innerHTML.replace(",", ".").replace(",",".") * 12;
```